# Does Git treat add/remove as a rename?

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

This may be more appropriate as an issue in whatever issue tracker/forum Git uses, but I thought I'd get an SO confirmation/explanation first:

I have a repo tracking a bunch of installer executables.

Let's say foo-1.0.exe is already in the repo.

I now add foo-2.0.exe in the same directory (git add foo-2.0.exe).  Next, I remove foo-1.0.exe (git rm foo-1.0.exe).

I expect Git status to show me one added file and one removed file.  Instead, I get this:

On branch master

Changes to be committed:

(use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

renamed:    foo-1.0.exe -> foo2.0.exe

That's a WTF for me... is Git using some sort of heuristic to guess that 2.0 is an update to 1.0... I can see how that might make sense, but I don't think I want it to do that in this case.

Comment: btw, I use version control only for source code. as long as you have a good build-systems the executables should be reproducible

Comment: Ha ha.  Yes, I know - that's how it SHOULD be done.  Your fancy one-click-builds are not welcome around these parts - give us a decade or so.

(plus some of the installers are third-party apps)

Answer (score 15):

You are correct that Git is using a heuristic. Git tracks only content, so the repository only knows that there used to be a `foo-1.0.exe` and now there is a `foo-2.0.exe`. In your case, `git status` is using the available information to *guess* that there might have been a rename (plus some minor changes, your two files are probably pretty similar). This guess will not affect what is recorded in the repository.

This philosophy of tracking only content and not deltas allows Git to evolve and provide better and better tools for navigating repository history. Eventually, Git will provide a way to track the evolution of a particular bit of code, at the function or even line level, through renames or refactoring or any other code modification. This can be done without the repository having to store this information beforehand.

Comment: You probably have Git configured to automatically detect renames (`diff.renames`).

Comment: @Jakub - if that works as expected, you may want your comment as an answer so I can accept it.  I'll test it soon-ish.

Greg, thanks for the overall insight.

Comment: Yeah... well... in my case git is completely wrong and it would have been great to know how to prevent such a thing from happening.